# iOS: How to show files-that-can-be-deleted in Settings.app?

Tags: ios, storage

In iOS, you can go to `Settings > General > iPhone Storage`, and see a list of apps that are using up space on your device.

Some apps, like Netflix, have figured out how to populate this screen with a list of large files, and some app-specific metadata (in this case, whether-the-episode-has-been-seen-yet).

What part of the iOS API would I need to look at to surface this information to the system?

[image]

Comment: It's possible that this isn't yet a public API -- I'm not finding any information, though that might just be accidental.

Comment: I've only seen this bhavior in a few apps (mostly Apple's, like the Podcast app, and I believe the Videos app on my iPad).  My guess is this is a private API that Apple has allowed for Netflix since they are such a big client.  Even an app like Plex, which would benefit greatly from this, does not offer this functionality.  Interestingly the section for the Podcast app is titled "Recommendations", so it seems like Apps have some control over the content of that section.

Comment: `Settings.bundle` offers only TextField/Title/ToggleSwitch/Group/Slider/MutilpleValue/ChildPane, but doesn't seem to have a UITableViewCells like this one.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out, it’s not a private API! It’s `AVAggregateAssetDownloadTask`.

Here is a link to the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetdownloadurlsession?language=objc

Comment: So I suppose it basically is an interface to download content that's normally supposed to be streamed. Do you have any idea if there are APIs that allow this to be used for other types of content?